# getOfferById method provided by an API does not work (invalid Id or Error cannot find parameter) [Laravel]

Tags: laravel, api, methods, service

I am a junior developer working on this project.

I'm using an API who provide offers and I'm trying to display them.
They provide several methods as "getOffers" "search" "getOfferById".
I managed to display all the offers with the getOffers, but I can't use the getOfferById. I might be using it the wrong way.

They also provide us with a sandbox to play with the methods so when I put the id on the sandbox it works fine. Here is an exemple from the doc:

```
$offer = $soapClient->getOfferById($offerId, array('key' => 'length.unit', 'value' => 'm'));
```

and here is what I've tried so far :

```
$offerId = 2020012100009;

$offer = $soapClient->getOfferById($offerId, array('key' => 'length.unit', 'value' => 'm'));

dd($offer->length);
```

I get "Error can not find parameter" for this.

```
$offer = $soapClient->getOfferById($offerId);
```

and I get "Invalid Id" for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. I had to apply it like that.

```
$offer = $soapClient->getOfferById(array(
            'id' => $offerId
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such id in the database, are you sure that the id you providing is valid?

Comment: Yes because when i use the getOfferById from the sandbox (it's a private website where i can play with their methods and offers)  and i put this id, it works fine.

Comment: Basically sandbox database and live database will be different.In sandbox the entry will be there,but in live database,it may not be there..

Comment: I'm not sure because i'm authentified on their service, so when I get all the offers with the getOffers method and return them in json, I do get the offers with the same ids as the sandbox database.